# Alfresco CMS issues

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

We have Alfresco (Community Edition 4.2) environment set on Server. WE created some websites and Custom content model and deployed on server.

We are facing following issues which need to resolved.

1. RTF Field : In custom content model we have defined a rtf field. This rtf field is not saving its value.
2. Folder Creation: There is no option available to create Folders in Document library.
3. Web Script Query: We need to write webscript queries to fetch the data for each website separately.

[image]

[image]

[image]

following is code from share-forms-config for RTF fields

```
<config evaluator="node-type" condition="custom:questionscategory">
    <forms>
        <!-- Default form configuration for the cm:content type -->
        <form>
            <field-visibility>
                <show id="cm:name" />
                <show id="custom:categoyTitle" />
                <show id="custom:categoryDesc" />
            </field-visibility>
            <appearance>
                <field id="custom:categoryDesc">
                   <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/richtext.ftl">
                  <control-param name="editorAppearance">full</control-param>
                   </control>                   
                </field>
            </appearance>
        </form>
        <form id="doclib-simple-metadata">
            <field-visibility>
                <show id="cm:name" />
                <show id="custom:categoyTitle" />
                <show id="custom:categoryDesc" />
            </field-visibility>
            <appearance>
                <field id="custom:categoryDesc">
                   <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/richtext.ftl">
                  <control-param name="editorAppearance">full</control-param>
                   </control>                   
                </field>
            </appearance>
        </form>
    </forms>
</config>
<config evaluator="model-type" condition="custom:questionscategory">
    <forms>
        <!-- Default form configuration for the cm:content type -->
        <form>
            <field-visibility>
                <show id="cm:name" />
                <show id="custom:categoyTitle" />
                <show id="custom:categoryDesc" />
            </field-visibility>
            <appearance>
                <field id="custom:categoryDesc">
                   <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/richtext.ftl">
                  <control-param name="editorAppearance">full</control-param>
                   </control>                   
                </field>
            </appearance>
        </form>
    </forms>
</config>
```

**here is the query I have written to fetch data..I need to add website name to it**

// locate folder by path
// NOTE: only supports path beneath company home, not from root
var query='TYPE:custom\:questionscategory';
var fbaQuetions = search.luceneSearch(query);
if (fbaQuetions== undefined || fbaQuetions.isContainer)
{
   status.code = 404;
   status.message = "fbaQuetions " + url.extension + " not found.";
   status.redirect = true;
 }
 model.folder = fbaQuetions;

Comment: RTF is Rich Text Field. The data type is Text associated with richtext.ftl

Comment: I can see that the meny option to create folder is missing. Is it possible to create a folder by clicking on the create folder in the "You can also"-section? Could someone have removed the menu option or is this a clean installation except from your customizations?

Comment: Yes it is possible to create folder through "You can also" section but that will appear only for the first time. Also, this is a fresh installation except these custom data models.

Answer (score 1):

For number 2. The answer probably lies in lack of permissions, make sure you have the right privileges in the site, that is at least contributor.

To answer your other questions we need more information:

- What do you mean by RTF-field? What datatype are we talking about? Could you post snippets from your custom model togheter with the appropriate share-forms-config section?
- There are a lot of webscripts present to fetch data per site. In fact Alfresco Share only uses webscripts to talk to the repository. What data do you need?

Update: Extend your search query with a "+PATH" which searches just in your site expression.

ie: "PATH:"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:yoursiteshortname//*"

Comment: I have updated the question with share-forms-config and screen shots

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug that has been patched, I've got a similar problem.
https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/MNT-10238?jql=text%20~%20%22r57658%22

I'm going to upgrade to get the patch.